# Remove special character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

It seems like a special character is causing a library I am using `xlsx-writestream` to fail to write an Excel file properly. I found that its `pawe2` string. It looks ok but on linux terminal it looks like:

[image]

Notice a weird character in between `e` and `2`. How can I remove such characters? I also notice that `"pawe�2".charCodeAt(4) = 20`. So it seems JavaScript can read it fine. Just that the output Excel file becomes corrupt in this case. What character is that? Somekind of emoji or something?

Comment: see if setting the document language to the language using the unknown character makes the problem go away automatically.

Comment: That's an [open bug](https://github.com/STRML/node-xlsx-writestream/issues/12) in xlsx-writestream.

Comment: Because XML does not allow every Unicode codepoint in a document, OpenXML has an escape mechanism. Your string should be written in the xlsx XML as pawe_x0014_2. If you put that in the JavaScript data that is to be converted to OpenXML, it is copied verbatim, Excel sees it as ␔ (U+0014) and is happy with it. (Which is a bug in xlsx-writestream because if I have pawe_x0014_2 in my JavaScript data, I want Excel to see exactly those characters.)

Answer (score 2):

You could remove all non-ascii characters (which is range 0 to 127) from the string:

```
str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
```

Whether or not this removes more from the string than desired depends on your requirements I suppose.

Comment: Seems like this doesnt remove the character. Do I need to convert the string to this format first? My string currently doesnt look like `\x00` for example?

Comment: @JiewMeng - You have to assign the result of the `.replace()` to something.  Strings are immutable so they aren't changed directly.  `.replace()` returns a new string.